# How to create View Controller and its Controls programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am populating a table view as menu using a custom table view cell and using it as menu.I am able to navigate to other views using navigation controller.

But I want to create views and its controls programmatically. Is it possible?

Can anyone please share me an example. Please find my menu structure in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible or not to create a UIViewController (or other) programmatically?

Comment: I have a UIViewController and I am pushing a custom view to that dynamic view controller. So based on the menu item selection I want to create the controls And add to the custom view. Then add this custom view to the dynamic view controller.  how should I pass a name to view to load its specific controls

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it. It works like a charm!!!

```
func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Remove the below line from this function as it will perform segue.
    //performSegue(withIdentifier: "DynamicSegue", sender: self)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // This will actually perform your segue
    var DestViewController = segue.destination as! DynamicSuperView 
    let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
    DestViewController.labelText = names[selectedRow!]
}
```